# Wygwam Embeds being Removed on Edit Entry

Tags: wygwam

Trying to embed a javascript embed, like from Survey Monkey, into a Wygwam 3.2.1 field and when the entry is edited and saved, the embed is removed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. I needed to set **Restrict allowed HTML?** to 'No' in the Wygwam configuration settings. This is located on the WYGWAM Module settings page. Works as expected now.

[image]